# how to delete a file which it'a time is later than the system time in linux system

Tags: linux

in my linux system, for some reason ,the time is not right for sometimes,
and in a folder where will be create log file by an applicaiton.

so i want to delete the file while it is time is later than system.

for example when the tiem is 20131212 ，and the file time is 20140202.

I has already trid to use find  . -mtime or stat -c etc,but i cannot got a running shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
touch /tmp/currtime
find . type f -newer /tmp/currtime -exec rm {} \;
```

`touch` sets the modification time of `/tmp/currtime` to now. Then `find` looks for any files whose modification time is later than that, and deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Barmar's method, touch a file `/tmp/currtime`
any file newer than `/tmp/currtime` will be in the future
alternatively you can do it without the temporary file

```
find . -newermt "1 second" -exec rm {} \;
```